# How to implement fixed row and scroll row for flex content in css

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

How can I implement a fixed row and a scrollable row for `flex` content in CSS? I want to implement a scroll bar for content. I want the first row to be fixed and the second row should scroll. Inside second row am splitting three row using flex layout

```
 .content{
    display:flex
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div class="content">
      <div class="row"></div> <!-- first row fixed -->
      <div class="row"></div> <!-- second row scrolls -->
    </div>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It is mess up with flex property if i used posistion:fixed

Comment: In which case we need to see a more complete example of your current HTML and CSS in order to help you debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help you. sample is available at [codepen][1][1]: https://codepen.io/vssadineni/pen/BGJeRN

```
<style>
    .content,
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.content {
  max-width: 86%;
  background-color: #cccccc80;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 12em;
}
.row {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.row[data-row="absolute"] {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  max-width: 22%;
  margin-right: 1em;
  color: blue;
}
.row[data-row="normal"] {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 76%;
  color: red;
  margin-left: 1em;
  height: 16em;
  overflow: scroll-y;
}
.row p {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
</style>


 <div class="content">
      <div class="row" data-row="absolute">
        <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.</p>
  </div> <!-- first row fixed -->
      <div class="row" data-row="normal">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tincidunt lorem quis turpis lobortis cursus. Mauris sodales lacinia nunc, a vestibulum augue interdum vel. Praesent facilisis ante ac dui lacinia sollicitudin. Maecenas id sem fringilla massa consectetur cursus et vitae ex. Aenean varius tempor pulvinar. Etiam cursus et augue in cursus. Donec eget purus convallis, dignissim eros et, vehicula lectus. Quisque vel lobortis quam, nec feugiat ipsum. Sed faucibus finibus diam, sed facilisis nisl scelerisque et. In diam nulla, sollicitudin vitae ullamcorper ac, blandit in magna. Pellentesque condimentum venenatis orci, quis viverra risus aliquam quis. Phasellus at sapien ut lorem faucibus tempor vel vitae tortor.</p><p>Sed sit amet mollis quam. Sed at mauris commodo, feugiat lorem vel, suscipit urna. Mauris eget quam sed nulla hendrerit commodo. Curabitur mollis mauris vel pulvinar efficitur. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed vehicula gravida dui, vel facilisis lectus vehicula ac. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean commodo in velit non pulvinar.</p><p>Donec sed massa venenatis, semper tellus vel, venenatis dui. Sed dignissim nisi elit, eu euismod ex rhoncus ac. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent at leo sagittis ante hendrerit ultrices a at tortor. Fusce viverra nibh vitae commodo venenatis. Donec consequat nulla ut nunc pulvinar iaculis. Integer vehicula gravida nunc. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus tellus dui, fermentum eget tempor nec, accumsan id dolor. Mauris vulputate libero ac orci consequat faucibus. Proin quis congue velit. Fusce et dictum sapien. Cras dui erat, hendrerit vel posuere a, feugiat accumsan dolor. Aenean vestibulum enim nisl, eu posuere tellus tempor et.</p><p>Vestibulum vel volutpat lacus. Praesent rutrum orci tempor rutrum condimentum. Nunc viverra vel elit id condimentum. Suspendisse pretium, diam vel bibendum facilisis, mauris nulla cursus est, eget aliquet massa erat in tellus. In dapibus aliquam imperdiet. Donec convallis tortor in eros lacinia bibendum. Mauris mollis metus laoreet neque rhoncus, eu vestibulum odio auctor. Nunc commodo faucibus tellus, eget mollis mauris auctor quis. Sed at dignissim ipsum, in volutpat quam. Sed et sollicitudin augue, vel tempus nibh.</p><p>Curabitur at sem massa. Morbi facilisis odio et nisi consequat, sed fermentum enim laoreet. Proin suscipit nunc at ante hendrerit pharetra. Pellentesque ac consectetur ipsum. Integer mattis justo non magna aliquet, vitae consectetur leo aliquet. Mauris consequat tincidunt condimentum. Pellentesque diam risus, consequat non vehicula ut, mollis in ex. Quisque nisl est, varius eget euismod ut, cursus sit amet ipsum. Donec elementum fringilla orci, id laoreet justo ultricies vel. Nunc ut commodo nisl. Donec laoreet quam ac hendrerit posuere. Sed luctus erat vel dui molestie, in rhoncus felis convallis.</p>
  </div> <!-- second row scrolls -->
</div>
```

Comment: height is conditional and I have added it for the example purpose only you can modify it as per your requirement. I did not use fixed property instead used sticky for fixing the first row with 22% width, if needed you can make it full width as well.